# Looking for solution save game data on appengine java

Tags: google-app-engine

I create a online game , using java-appengine as backend .
// My game using websocket , use channel API 
But i some object need persistence live on application .

- Static object is good but in appengine it is bad , because instance start-stop is can't managed
- - Memcache is same , can't control when it exp (have way make it never exp ?)
- - Datastore is veryslow and expensive

I Looking for solution save game object on appengine java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run on a backend, but it really doesn't scale as well.

What you probably need to do is determine whether App Engine is actually the platform you want to use for building your game.  If the datastore performance is not cutting it for you, you probably want another architecture.  Most likely you want a more traditional client/server architecture.

Also, without any more information on your game's architecture, it's very hard to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry .   // My game using websocket , use channel API

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is the way to go, you can't control it, but if you want to use app engine there will be compromises.  My experience with Memcache on python is that mostly while an instance is running the cache is valid.  It doesn't seem to expire all that often even between close instances.  When I check my logs I normally only see Memcache creating an expired object when there is a significant time between instances (hour+).

You should profile your code on both Java and Python it could be that Python with it's faster startup time will be a better fit for your application.  Or if you must use java you might want to keep several idle instances going to be able to handle the request without startup lag.  You might be able to use Cron tasks to keep the memcache fresh I haven't tried this yet as my code normally isn't that sensitive.